# google dataflow firewall rule/network tag

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to connect to cassandra (which have firewall rule tags) from google dataflow batch, , moreover the dataflow service will create workers with 'dataflow' tagged.

is it possible to change the default tag ? or add more tags? .

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is currently not possible to change the labels with which Dataflow service creates the VMs. However, it is possible to control which GCE network the Dataflow workers will belong to, by specifying the parameter `--network`: *The Google Compute Engine network for launching Compute Engine instances to run your pipeline*  (see [Specifying Pipeline Execution Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params)).

You may consider [creating a network](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/create) for your Dataflow workers and using that in the firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to change the tag. However, firewall rules can select instances by service account in lieu of network tag, and the service account can be specified through the `--serviceAccount` account option. See "Specifying a user-managed controller service account" within [the Dataflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions).