# Dataflow Shared VPC Networking

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-networking

Is it possible to execute GCE instances belonging to a Dataflow pipeline on a Shared VPC (ex-XPN) network/subnetwork and with private IP addresses?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45043587/278042

Comment: Not entirely because is about VPC network and Shared VPC. To be sure I've to try the setup with a Shared VPC, because there's no documentation and no stackoverflow questions about this specific setup. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usage of Shared VPC is documented in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks.

Private IP addresses are fully supported with Java SDK.

Comment: Please post all the essential information *in your answer itself*, not in a link

Answer (score 0):

I found this today that helped...

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params

It allows you to set the "network" with the --network arg to set the VPC.